# How to get the length of an array from JSON then run a function X number of times

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get the number of items in an array then run a function that amount of times. Is this possible in JavaScript? I am storing the array in JSON.

This is the code I have set up for when there is only 1 app

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("repo")) {
  repo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("repo"));
  create_app(repo.app.appName, repo.app.appIcon, repo.app.appId, repo.app.appUrl);
};
```

This is what the JSON looks like. The array I am trying to access is called "apps".

```json
{
    "repoName": "repo_name",
    "repoId": "unique_id",
    "repoVer": "1",
    "apps": [{
        "appName": "first app name"
        "appId": "app1",
        "appUrl": "https://example.com",
        "appIcon": "https://example.com/favicon.ico"
      },
    {
      "appName": "second app name",
      "appId": "app2",
      "appUrl": "https://example.org",
      "appIcon": "https://example.org/favicon.ico"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Since `repo.apps` is an array you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repo.apps.length` will give you the number of items in `apps`

Also, since you've already parsed your data into JSON object `repo`, it now can understand your `repo.apps` is an array and you can just loop over it directly likes:

```
repo.apps.forEach((app) => {})
```

or

```
for (let app in repo.apps) {}
```

etc

Hope this help

Comment: what does `let app in repo.apps` do?

Comment: the context is `for (key in array)` which means we're looping every `app` as key `in` array `repo.apps` but `app` wasn't declared before, so we have to declare it with `let`